# String methods like replace not working in JSP inside %{ } ognl tag

Tags: string, jsp, struts2, ognl

I a m using struts2
`<s:set var="varMsg" value='%{"ok".toUppercase()}' />` is not working
but `<s:set var="varMsg" value='%{"ok".toString()}' />`   is working 
I want to use a replaceAll inside jsp but String methods are not understood.

I tried to import java.lang.String `<%@ page import="java.lang.String" %>` it did'nt work

Comment: 1) `java.lang` is imported by default so it wouldn't matter anyway. 2) This kind of work should be done on the back-end anyway, not at the view layer. 3) It's `toUpperCase()`.

Comment: thx uppercase works but not replaceAll when using p{smothing}
for example : `System.out.println(pieceUploaded.replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", ""));` works in the action
but `<s:set var="varMsg" value='%{piece.toString().replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "")}' />` does not work in JSP
simple replaceAll("é","e") works

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What's `piece`? What's `piece.toString()`? Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page: it's impossible to help without knowing precisely what you're doing. But again: this kind of work doesn't belong in the view layer.

Comment: Ok. 
`<s:set var="varMsg" value='%{"Ecrit client et ou agence concernée".toString().replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "")}' /> <s:property value='%{varMsg}'/>` does not work means it shows nothing. it is like an empty value.
but when >I use replaceAll("é","e") it works

Comment: I think my solution is to escape brackets in ognl %{}
\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks} is not recognised in jsp because of brackets